# What to do after a kernel panic on AIX?

Tags: aix, kernel-panic

There was a "kernel panic" - at least sort of.

```
errpt | head
IDENTIFIER TIMESTAMP  T C RESOURCE_NAME  DESCRIPTION
A6DF45AA   1205044411 I O RMCdaemon      The daemon is started.
67145A39   1205044111 U S SYSDUMP        SYSTEM DUMP
F48137AC   1205043911 U O minidump       COMPRESSED MINIMAL DUMP
0975DD6C   1205043911 P S ABEND          KERNEL ABNORMALLY TERMINATED
9DBCFDEE   1205044311 T O errdemon       ERROR LOGGING TURNED ON
E87EF1BE   1204150011 P O dumpcheck      The largest dump device is too small.
A6DF45AA   1204012511 I O RMCdaemon      The daemon is started.
67145A39   1204012311 U S SYSDUMP        SYSTEM DUMP
F48137AC   1204012111 U O minidump       COMPRESSED MINIMAL DUMP
```

How do I analyze the dumpfile? How can I trace what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dump space is too small. It could not store a full dump.

`sysdumpdev -e` will give you an estimate of how much dump space you'll need to capture a full dump. I would suggest you provide a dump LV with at least 1.5x or 2x the estimated size.

`sysdumpdev -l` will show you the current dump device configuration.

You can modify the dump devices with some other flags, or via `smit sysdumpdev`.

A dump device is simply a logical volume of type `dump`. It's recommended that the primary dump device be live on local disk, preferably within `rootvg`.

Since you at least have the minimal dump, the best action would be (assuming you have IBM support) to open a case with IBM and upload the dump file within a snap (`snap -ac`) to them according to their instructions.

They will analyze the snap and dump, and (hopefully) suggest some corrective actions. Best case you stumbled upon a specific bug that has been fixed, but more than likely they will recommend you upgrade to the latest service pack for your technology level.